# I want to disable android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION in my Xamarin app

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-permissions

I want to disable android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION in my Xamarin app because I dont need it anymore but when I uncheck the checkbox in the Properties tab:

[image]

And delete the permission request in the android.manifest file itself:

[image]

The permission request still seems to be there according to the manifest file from the archived .aab file and also according to the google play dev console.
I also searched my entire solution and dident find any other references.
Is there anything that causes this request or anything I forgot to delete?

Comment: Using any 3rd party libs that use that  perm?

Comment: Have you checked to see if it is being added via the `AssemblyInfo.cs` in your Android project?

Comment: @SushiHangover - I have a question about that. I've always assumed that if the app manifest didn't list it that the 3rd party lib would simply fail (if you used a feature that needed it). Am I wrong?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve themanifest is frozen in time once through the build process, but the final app manifest is the result of merging your main manifest along w/ your dependencies, and of course Xamarin's attribute based perms that are extracted and merged during the build.

Comment: @CodingLumis was right, it is included in the `AssemblyInfo.cs` after removing it there everything works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was defined in the `AssemblyInfo.cs` and after removing it there everything was fixed.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Check the *merged* `AndroidManifest.xml` in `obj\Release\nnn\`.

If it is there, then something in your build process has added it.

If it is not there, then add to your question more details about how you build and launch to google play dev console - what you are seeing at dev console should match what is in the obj version of that file.